# Using IPC for different systems

Tags: ipc

Hii ,

I was asked this question in a recent interview for which i didnt answer as i was relatively new to IPC .

How would you use IPC if the processes are on different systems ?

Comment: Sockets and message passing are the first that spring to mind..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPC just means Inter Process Communications. There are many ways for processes to communicate, There really is no difference if two processes are local to the same machine or not.

If you are talking across machines, some forms are not available to you such as Shared Memory, Signal, Pipe, Memory mapped File or Semaphore. (There is middleware that can simulate shared memory if you really want to go that route).

Some of the more common methods are:

**File**    Most operating systems.
**Signal**  Most operating systems; some systems, such as Windows, only implement signals in   the C run-time library and do not actually provide support for their use as an IPC technique.
**Socket**  Most operating systems.
**Message queue**   Most operating systems.
**Pipe**    All POSIX systems, Windows.
**Named pipe**  All POSIX systems, Windows.
**Semaphore**   All POSIX systems, Windows.
**Shared memory**   All POSIX systems, Windows.
**Message passing**
(shared nothing)    Used in MPI paradigm, Java RMI, CORBA, MSMQ, MailSlots and others.
**Memory-mapped file**  All POSIX systems, Windows. This technique may carry race condition risk if a temporary file is used.

**Edit:** This list is taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). The list is as good as any.

Comment: Unless you wrote the [Wikipedia article on IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), that list is blatantly copied.

Answer (score 0):

IPC is an abstract term which denotes any interprocess communication between processes residing on the same or different systems.

If you have processes on different systems, most obvious are TCP-based communications, including IPC tools that use TCP as a transport. But of course this is not the only way to exchange information.

Answer (score 0):

IPC is Inter Process Communication, more of a technique to share data across different processes **within** one machine, in such a way that data passing binds the coupling of different processes.

- The first, is using memory mapping techniques, where a memory map is created, and others open the memory map for reading/writing...
- The second is, using sockets, to communicate with one another...this has a high overhead, as each process would have to open up the socket, communicate across... although effective
- The third, is to use a pipe or a named pipe, a very good example can be found [here](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html)

There are complications, such as what if one process is written in one language, and the other process written in another, how do you guarantee the data flow is compatible for each process to read, you could use Google's Protocol Buffer to handle [this](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), there is a .NET version available, [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

Although to a varying degree, IPC mechanisms are only transparent and work within the one domain, such as Windows to Windows, Linux to Linux, you *may* be able to do so with a Windows to Linux or vice versa, although caution must be heeded, as API differences and functionalities dictate the outcome to an agreement of data transfer encoding scheme.

Comment: May I ask and remind respectfully that it is ignorant to downvote without leaving a comment? Explain why?

Comment: I did not down vote you - but your answer is plainly wrong. IPC is not for sharing data within one machine. The purpose of most middleware is to enable communications across machines as well as on the same machine. Application location is independent in many IPC mechanisms.  Most middleware packages handle cross language and cross CPU architectures for you. The OS is also transparent in many mechanisms. The idea is to simply pick one that works within the constraints that you have. There are many choices as you can see in my post.